# How can I use Sitecore Rules in Scriban templates in SXA 9.3

Tags: sxa, scriban

In SXA 9.3 we have the possibility of using [Scriban Templates](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/scriban-templates.html). I wonder if there is a possibility to use Sitecore rules engine inside of those templates. Let say that I would like to render part of template only if my context item meets certain rule.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep! You can do it by adding Rule item under your Sriban template item and using `sc_evaluate` function inside of the template.

**Example:**

I have a page which has two fields:

- Title
- Brand

And I want to render Brand field only when it is Monday.

In order to do that I'm using Page Content rendering (can be any other) with following [rendering variant](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/rendering-variants.html):

[image]

And the rule looks like this:

[image]

That is pretty it! The `sc_evaluate i_item "DayOfWeek"` in the `if` statement will evaluate the "DayOfWeek" rule against context item and base on this will render the Brand field or not.

If you would like to evaluate the rule against other embedded objects (e.g.: data source item) the list of those you will find [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-embedded-items-and-objects-in-the-scriban-context.html).